# Objeto vem null na consulta, mesmo existindo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho esse método em minha controller

```
[HttpDelete]
        public HttpResponseMessage DeletaCidade(int id)
        {
            Cidade cidade = banco.Cidades.Find(id);

            if (cidade == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

            banco.Cidades.Remove(cidade);

            try
            {
                banco.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, cidade);
        }
```

o que passa é quando eu passo um id válido, eu recebo na controller, mas o objeto cidade continua NUll. Como eu resolvo isso?

**EDIT1**

Minha Model

```
public class Cidade
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]         
        public String nome { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `Cidade cidade = banco.Cidades.Find(id);` retorna algo ?

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti, não. cidade vem NULL, mas o ID=33, por exemplo tem a cidade de "Varsóvia", por exemplo.

Comment: o problema esta na consulta então, teria como editar e colocar a classe `banco` de `banco.Cidades.Find(id);`

Comment: Porque estão fazendo isso comigo? Não me querem mais na comunidade? A pergunta é válida e não ampla, ela permite apenas uma resposta. Só downvote

Comment: também não sei o que anda acontecendo, me negativam por nada... relaxa

Comment: A primeira coisa que você tem que se certificar é que a coleção Cidades tem algum conteúdo. Já verificou?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade, no break nessa linha: `Cidade cidade = banco.Cidades.Find(id);` cidade está null, não tem nada, apenas null. Entendi o que vc quer dizer

Comment: Se `banco.Cidades`estiver vazio é certo que o método find não vai encontrar nada.

Comment: Entendi. Não sei o que fazer nesse  caso, pois antes eu fiz uns métodos fora da Controller e nesse caso estava funcionando. Mudei para deixar na controller e aí não funcionou mais

Comment: Sua questão parte de uma falsa premissa :"mesmo existindo". Na verdade sua questão não pode ser respondida porque o erro não está no código apresentado. Quando você diz "*A pergunta é válida e não ampla, ela permite apenas uma resposta*". Ela é imprecisa. A titulo de comparação é como você perguntasse "Por que meu computador não liga?", mas esqueceu de verificar se havia corrente elétrica no prédio.Entendeu?

Comment: @pnet, antes de lançar uma pergunta aqui, faça o debug do seu código, método por método e linha por linha